# Iterative deepening in minimax - sorting all legal moves, or just finding the PV-move then using MVV-LVA?

Tags: chess, minimax, iterative-deepening

After reading the chessprogramming wiki and other sources, I've been confused about what the exact purpose of iterative deepening. My original understanding was the following:

*It consisted of minimax search performed at depth=1, depth=2, etc. until reaching the desired depth. After a minimax search of each depth, sort the root-node moves according to the results from that search, to make for optimal move ordering in the next search with depth+1, so in the next deeper search,the PV-move is searched, then the next best move, then the next best move after that, and so on.*

Is this correct? Doubts emerged when I read about MVV-LVA ordering, specifically about ordering captures, and additionally, using hash tables and such. For example, [this page](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Move_Ordering) recommends a move ordering of:

1. PV-move of the principal variation from the previous iteration of an iterative deepening framework for the leftmost path, often implicitly done by 2.
2. Hash move from hash tables
3. Winning captures/promotions
4. Equal captures/promotions
5. Killer moves (non capture), often with mate killers first
6. Non-captures sorted by history heuristic and that like
7. Losing captures

If so, then what's the point of sorting the minimax from each depth, if only the PV-move is needed? On the other hand, if the whole point of ID is the PV-move, won't it be a waste to search from every single minimax depth up till desired depth just to calculate the PV-move of each depth?

**What is the concrete purpose of ID, and how much computation does it save?**

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think you are mixing 2 different concepts here.

Iterative deepening is mainly used to set a maximum search time for each move. The AI will go deeper and deeper, and then when the decided time is up it returns the move from the latest depth it finished searching. Since each increase in depth leads to exponentially longer search times, searching each depth from e.g. 1 to 12 take almost the same time as only searching with depth 12.

Sorting the moves is done to maximize the effect of alpha-beta pruning. If you want an optimal alpha-beta pruning you look at the best move first. Which is of course impossible to know beforehand, but the points you stated above is a good guess. Just make sure that the sorting algorithm doens't slow down your recursive function, and by that removing the effect from the alhpa-beta.

Hope this helps and that I understood your question correctly.